# rails - Store DateTime objects in same time zone as timestamps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

When i save a DateTime `schedule_time` to the DB, it saves according to my local time, but the timestamps (created_at) are saved apparently in UTC (7 hours ahead of my pacific time)

So if i submit the form setting my `schedule_time` for right now it will be 7 hours different than my `created_at`.

i need to show many users their times in their own selected zone, and i also need to compare times against each other, so i want all db entries to be in the same zone.  Testing on my machine, my user has his zone saved as Pacific (-7:00), but its saving `schedule_time` in local time, not really UTC, so when i try to display the time back like this:

```
@item.schedule_time.in_time_zone(@user.time_zone)
```

it actually takes the stored datetime and subtracts seven hours from it giving me 7 hours before i wanted.  i think the best thing is to just store all the datetimes in a uniform way so i can compare them easily.

changing this value `config.time_zone = 'UTC'` does nothing to change the stored format of my datetime.  it stores in my local time regardless, while storing the timepstamps in real UTC.

ive also tried to reformat the datetime before storing it, with `in_time_zone(@user.time_zone)` but it had no effect on the stored time.

if i can just get `schedule_time` stored in UTC just like my timestamps are stored i could make this work!  any ideas?

Comment: `schedule_time = schedule_time.utc` should do the trick, before storing it in DB

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store `schedule_time` converted to UTC before storing it in the database, you can include a `before_save` callback in your `Item` model to convert it as follows:

```
before_save { |item| item.schedule_time = item.schedule_time.utc }
```

Comment: its not working for me.  i tried the `before_save` method and also just creating the ActiveRecord item with schedule_time.utc before the save.  as i said any attempt to transform the datetime seems to have no effect on what is actually saved.  in the case of the last attempt, the db shows the schedule_time as `2014-10-25 14:01:03.000000` and the created_at as `2014-10-25 21:01:08.834657`.  To be clear the schedule_time is in my local time, the same exact time i submitted into the form.

Comment: did you restart the server or `rails console` after changing `time_zone` to `config.time_zone = 'UTC'` ?

Comment: somehow, it seems to think it's saving in UTC even though its showing my local time.  if i do a `schedule_time.utc?` i get true.  its as if it thinks UTC is just +0.  so by not adding any hours its UTC.  whatever it thinks its doing, my `schedule_time` is clearly in my local time, and my timestamps are clearly +7 from there (equivalent to UTC).  timestamps also return true for `created_at.utc?`

Comment: What do you get if you type `Time.current` and `Time.current.utc` in your rails console ?

Comment: im restarting rails server and rails console every time i make a change, just to make sure im not delirious.  which i obviously am.

Comment: `Time.current` and `Time.current.utc` give the same time, formatted a bit differently `Sat, 25 Oct 2014 21:28:15 UTC +00:00`.  the time they give is the UTC time that my timestamps are using.  I can't seem to affect the time that my DateTime stores.  when i set up a new Item for saving, i tried setting my schedule_time to `params[:item][:schedule_time].to_datetime.in_time_zone('Arizona')` ... which works at least to change the time in console, but doesnt do anything to change the times i'm storing in the db.  i still store the time in my local time.

Answer (score 0):

sorry i was totally on the wrong track.

the issue was with the jquery date picker i was using (will_pickdate).  it returns a date and time but with a +0000 time zone offset.  by default, the picker autofills with the current local time, but when i submitted that, rails basically thought it was receiving a time in UTC and added it as my local time but with +0000.

in order to store the date properly i have to keep the time and date from the picker intact, but just shift the +0000 part to something appropriate:

```
my_time.change(offset: user_time_zone_offset)
```